# How to use decrypt part of the encrypt.dart - "SOLVED"

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption

I'd like to know how to use the decrypt part of the encrypt.dart package.
I have a function that encrypt the data I want to keep in the database and this function is working properly.

It receives a String, crypt it and return this string encrypted.

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as myencry;
String criptografaAES(String txtEncriptar) {
    final key = myencry.Key.fromUtf8(UserAdmConsts.KEY);
    final iv = myencry.IV.fromLength(16);
    final encrypter =myencry.Encrypter(myencry.AES(key, mode: myencry.AESMode.ecb));

    final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(txtEncriptar, iv: iv).base64;
    return encrypted;

}
```

At some point I need to recover this, then I tried to pass this encrypted string to a function that decrypt it, like so:

```
String decriptografaAES(myencry.Encrypted vlEncripted) {
    final key = myencry.Key.fromUtf8(UserAdmConsts.KEY);
    final iv = myencry.IV.fromLength(16);
    final encrypter = myencry.Encrypter(myencry.AES(key, mode: myencry.AESMode.ecb));

    final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(vlEncripted, iv: iv);
    return decrypted.toString();
}
```

**But the problem, which I don't know to solve, is that vlEncripted must be of the type Encrypted. It can't not be a String. The value that I'm keeping in the database is a String on MariaDB.**

Trying to solve this I tried to do a cast, like so:

```
String decriptografaAES(String vlDecriptar) {

    myencry.Encrypted vlEncripted = vlDecriptar as myencry.Encrypted;
    final key = myencry.Key.fromUtf8(UserAdmConsts.KEY);
    final iv = myencry.IV.fromLength(16);
    final encrypter = myencry.Encrypter(myencry.AES(key, mode: myencry.AESMode.ecb));
    final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(vlEncripted, iv: iv);

    return decrypted.toString();

}
```

I receive: (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Encrypted' in type cast) So, How do I change the string value to a Encrypted data type? I'll appreciate any help, thank you.

The solution was create a Encrypted object, like so:

```
String decriptografaAES(String vlDecriptar) {
    myencry.Encrypted vlEncripted = myencry.Encrypted.from64(vlDecriptar);
    final key = myencry.Key.fromUtf8(UserAdmConsts.KEY);
    final iv = myencry.IV.fromLength(16);
    final encrypter =
        myencry.Encrypter(myencry.AES(key, mode: myencry.AESMode.ecb));
    final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(vlEncripted, iv: iv);
    return decrypted.toString();
  }
```

***Thanks to @Topaco, who give me the direction.***

Comment: There are some formatting problems in your question

Comment: The ciphertext is Base64 encoded, with [`Encrypted.from64()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/encrypt/latest/encrypt/Encrypted/Encrypted.from64.html) an [`Encrypted`](https://pub.dev/documentation/encrypt/latest/encrypt/Encrypted-class.html) object can be created from it. Note that the code contains some vulnerabilities: ECB mode, static IV, possible use of a passphrase as key (with regard to the UTF-8 encoding).